# I cannnot find ssl.conf for TLS1.2 install

Tags: centos, openssl, ssl

I have a dedicated server with CENTOS 6.7, Apache/2.4.20 php 7 and i want to enable TLS1.2 for paypal payments. From [this](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976123) I understand that i need to add extra lines in ssl.conf

I looked for it in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and in `/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.conf`.

I also tried locate ssl.conf and got no result.
Following this answer  : [What do I do if I can't find ssl.conf file in a CentOS server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263401/what-do-i-do-if-i-cant-find-ssl-conf-file-in-a-centos-server) i tried to

```
sudo yum install mod_ssl
```

but i get this answer

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* EA4: 159.253.142.50
* base: mirror.checkdomain.de
* extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
* updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
No package mod_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

same for

```
sudo yum reinstall mod_ssl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS1.2 is not available in the OpenSSL supplied with CentOS 6.7.

Your options are:

- Upgrade to CentOS 7
- Try installing the `rpm` from a later version - very dangerous with OpenSSL, as you risk breaking many packages.
- Compile your own version of OpenSSL - needs constant maintenance every time a patch is released.

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84283/how-can-i-get-tlsv1-2-support-in-apache-on-rhel6-centos-sl6) has some more options.

By your own admission, you're not familiar with Linux administration so I would think very careful about any of the above options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , It seems that i have no option since i cannot upgrade (i have already 20 websites hosted there) and i'm not skilfull enouh to do the no 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

TLS1.2 is available for apache, to add TLS1.2 you just need to add in your https virtual host configuration:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer but unfortunately i;m not familiar with linux server administration : I should do that in httpd.conf file ?

Comment: have a look at this link `http://superuser.com/questions/882638/sslciphersuite-settings-in-apache-for-supporting-tls-1-0-1-1-and-1-2`